# Virtual inheritance and parametrized constructors

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Default constructor and virtual inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524019/default-constructor-and-virtual-inheritance)

```
class Base
{
private:
    int number;
protected:
    Base(int n) : number(n) {}
public:
    virtual void write() {cout << number;}     
};

class Derived1 : virtual public Base
{
private:
    int number;
protected:
    Derived1(int n, int n2) : Base(n), number(n2) {}
public:
    virtual void write() {Base::write(); cout << number;}
};

class Derived2 : virtual public Base
{
private:
    int number;
protected:
    Derived2(int n, int n2) : Base(n), number(n2) {}
public:
    virtual void write() {Base::write(); cout << number;}
};

class Problematic : public Derived1, public Derived2
{
private:
    int number;
public:
    Problematic(int n, int n2, int n3, int n4) : Derived1(n, n2), Derived2(n, n3), number(n4) {}
    virtual void write() {Derived1::write(); Derived2::write(); cout << number;}
};

int main()
{
    Base* obj = new Problematic(1, 2, 3, 4);
    obj->write();
}
```

In other words:

```
Base
| \
|  \
|   \
|    \
D1   D2
|    /
|   /
|  /
| /
Problematic
```

I'm trying to get "1 2 1 3 4" on the output. The compiler, however, keeps complaining that I need a parameterless constructor in Base, but when I add one, the "1" turns to garbage. Any ideas on how to approach it? Is it even possible to solve the diamond pattern using a parametrized constructor?

Comment: You're missing ;'s on the derived classes

Comment: @cppguy - I don't see it, but it's not the real code anyway (probably just a typo).

Comment: @MaciejStachowski ildjarn added it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Calling a virtual base class's overloaded constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495139/calling-a-virtual-base-classs-overloaded-constructor), it looks like if the inheritance is virtual, the most derived class must call the base class constructor.

```
Problematic(int n, int n2, int n3, int n4) : Derived1(n, n2), Derived2(n, n3), Base(n), number(n4) {}
```

Comment: So, that means that all the classes inheriting from Derived1/2 or any of their subclasses have to call Base constructor? My love for C++ has just shrunk a little.